# Visual Studio 2019 - force C++11 features only

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio 2019 for C++ development. Due to constraints of legacy systems that code will be deployed to, I am limited to using only C++11 language features (specifically GCC 4.8.5).

The default in VS2019 is C++14, which is obviously a super set of C++11. I can't see a way to specify C++11 only. This would be useful as a much faster way to see if I accidentally include newer C++ features than seeing things fail in the build system.

Is there any way to change this setting?

Comment: You have to install and use VS2017.

Comment: note: GCC 4.8.5 isn't even C++11 it's pre standardization. The equivalent is either VS2010 or VS2013. I'd strongly suggest upgrading your GCC instead if possible or plausible.

Comment: Unfortunately that is out of my control, But I will keep pushing for it :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's not possible.

> there is no plan to add a C++11 switch

Link: [Standards version switches in the compiler](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/)

> The compiler doesn't support standards options for C++98, C++03, or
> C++11.

[/Zc:__cplusplus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160#remarks)